Copy only file path
Whenever I copy-paste file path from the drop down menu I get this:
x-special/nautilus-clipboard 
copy 
file://<file-path>/<filename>

I just want:
<file-path>/<filename>

I am using RedHat8 with Gnome Version 3.32.2. I understand this is a Nautilus issue. And I am aware of the workarounds here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/634#note_495203
But they don't work for me.
Does anyone have a solution -- a script that works under nautilus?

FWIW with nautilus 46.2 here, I don't see a "copy/paste file path" context menu, only "Copy" and "Copy to". xclip -sel c -target TARGETS -o after copying a file returns text/plain;charset=utf-8
text/uri-list
application/vnd.portal.files application/vnd.portal.filetransfer
x-special/gnome-copied-files
UTF8_STRING
TARGETS
TIMESTAMP and only the x-special/gnome-copied-files target returns something similar to your output (without the first line), UTF8_STRING as would be queried when pasting as text returns the file path.
